# If $N \unlhd G$, $G/N$ solvable, $\chi \in Irr(G)$, $\psi \in Irr(N)$ and $<\chi_N , \psi>_{_N} \neq 0$, then $(\chi(1)/\psi(1)) | [G:N]$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

If $N \unlhd G$, $G/N$ solvable, $\chi \in Irr(G)$, $\psi \in Irr(N)$ and  $\langle\chi_N , \psi\rangle_{_N} \neq 0$, then $(\chi(1)/\psi(1)) | [G:N]$.

Can anybody help me to prove that?

Comment: Is this an exercise from Isaacs? Because as far as I recall, the assumption of solvability is not needed (though the proof takes a lot more work in that case), and it might be nice to know how deep results you are expected to use.

Comment: I want to prove that with solvability assumption.

Comment: And that would also follow from the general result. I asked because you will probably learn most from the proof using only those results already covered in whatever book you got the exercise from. So this information would be good to have.

Comment: Sure! without "solvability assumption" is so better, by I'm new to representation theory!

Comment: The stronger version is Corollary 11.29 in Isaacs book on Character theory (in fact, $N$ only needs to be subnormal for this to work). How to do it more directly with the added assumption of solvability, I will need to think a bit more about, though as far as I recall, one can do it by induction on the derived length of $G/N$.

Comment: What if? Let $\chi$ be afforded by $V$, $\psi$ by $W\subseteq V$, $H$ the inertial subgroup. The sum $V'$ of $h\cdot W, h\in H$ is an isotypic $N$-module. 
If $G/H=\{g_1,\ldots,g_k\}$, then $V=\sum_i g_i V'$ is a direct sum of $N$-modules each of same dimension as $V'$. So $\dim V=[G:H]\dim V'$. If $K$ is the (setwise) stabilizer of $W$ inside $H$, then obviously $N\le K$. Don't we have $\dim V'=[H:K]\dim W$ and thus
$$\dim V=[G:K]\dim W?$$ Cutting corners here - mostly trying to find a line of attack on the problem.